# Codeigniter 3 Show All Online User

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am using database level session store method.

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';//its your table name name
```

So when user login data inserted into ci_sessions successfully.

```
__ci_last_regenerate|i:1435420891;identity|s:13:"john@doe.com ";username|s:13:"johndoe";email|s:13:"john@doe.com ";user_id|s:1:"5";old_last_login|s:10:"1435412865";
```

Like this, this table may contains multiple records. I want to show all the online user. This data column has blob type. How can I fetch all the username?

Comment: I would do it using `websocket`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get information using following code.

```
$session_data   = '__ci_last_regenerate|i:1435420891;identity|s:13:"john@doe.com ";username|s:13:"johndoe";email|s:13:"john@doe.com ";user_id|s:1:"5";old_last_login|s:10:"1435412865"'; //session data

$return_data    = array();  // array where you put your "BLOB" resolved data
$offset         = 0;
while ($offset < strlen($session_data)) {
    if (!strstr(substr($session_data, $offset), "|")) {
        throw new Exception("invalid data, remaining: " . substr($session_data, $offset));
    }
    $pos        = strpos($session_data, "|", $offset);
    $num        = $pos - $offset;
    $varname    = substr($session_data, $offset, $num);
    $offset     += $num + 1;
    $data       = unserialize(substr($session_data, $offset));
    $return_data[$varname] = $data;  
    $offset     += strlen(serialize($data));
}

echo $return_data['username'];
echo $return_data['email'];
```

Thanks